# Webpack: use node's require.resolve() instead of webpack's

Tags: webpack, electron, electron-builder

I have an electron project which uses a ceratin nodejs lib (@grpc/proto-loader). 
Production build doesn't work, because webpack replaces **require.resolve()** with its own function which returns module IDs instead of paths. How to prevent webpack from doing this?

I tried to add the problematic package to "externals", but that doesn't seem to work.

I want the app to use node's require() function.
I know non_webpack_require could be used, but I can't modify the code of the package, it's a 3rd party lib. So is there a better way?

Comment: You can use ```window.require``` instead of ```require```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a hack to fix this: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node/issues/969#issuecomment-633271735

Update your `webpack.config.js` to have a new loader (specify it first):

```js
...
  rules: [
    {
       test: /@grpc\/proto-loader/,
       use: path.resolve('scripts/remove-proto-loader-protos.js'),
    },
...
```

Then create file `scripts/remove-proto-loader-protos.js` with the following code:

```js
// https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node/issues/969
module.exports = function (source) {
  if (source.includes(`Load Google's well-known proto files`)) {
    return source.replace(/\/\/ Load Google's well-known proto files.*?\n}/gis, '')
  } else {
    return source
  }
}
```

That's it! The proto loading code will be automatically *wiped out*. No need for separate forks and keeping them updated manually.

This of course means that if anyone needs those proto files, you have to load them manually. Also, if Google updates their code, this hack may need to be updated in the future. I know, this is a hack, but what can you do? `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`